# Approach for real time data feed from one table to another

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement that data is fed from two external applications to my .NET/SQL Server table/app. In the past I have used XML batches that get processed nightly, and the user then scans and approves the incoming data through UI. However they want real time feed.

The client team's current plan is to use triggers and sp_send_dbmail. The process will begin with the external apps posting data directly into my staging tables (using ETL). Then in my triggers I will need to check some constraints (check for example if incoming ID exists). If constraints pass, then all the records will get inserted/updated in my target tables/app. If not, (say missing ID) then the current architecture suggests sending email using sp_send_dbemail. I have tested the triggers and all the components work.

I am jumping into the project midstream. Is there a better way of doing it? Is there a way you can set up real time feed without using triggers? If I can convince end users to an hourly process, maybe use job agents with stored procedures to do the hourly update and then do a UI for the user for records that error out?

I do not want to use triggers for all the well documented reasons (performance, lack of transparency, not enough granular control, handling batch insert problem etc). And getting multiple emails for errors could get chaotic for the end user.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Triggers sounds like they meet the real-time requirements of your process.  If real-time is needed, you basically have two approaches:

- Use triggers to implement the logic.
- Write stored procedure wrappers that implement the trigger logic.

Personally, I prefer the second approach, but it depends how the data is being fed in.  If it is one record at a time, then the stored procedure is reasonable to capture the relevant fields, do the checks, and then do the subsequent insertion into final or staging tables.  If multiple records are coming over in batches, then this is harder to implement.

The reason I prefer stored procedures is because they are more versatile.  They don't hold locks unneessarily, while doing things like writing audit records and validating the data.  They are more flexible, because they allow dynamic SQL and other constructs not allowed in triggers.  I also find the logic easier to follow.  In addition, a call to a stored procedure can be delayed if the server is busy.  Once a trigger is called, you are in the middle of a transaction.

However, if the design is reasonable and already half-implemented, switching the methods in the middle is possibly not a good idea.  Perhaps the idea of using triggers to validate the data and then a job that runs every 5, 10, or 60 minutes will meet user requirements.  If work-load on the server is an issue, then batched processing (i.e. using scheduled jobs) may be more appropriate than a trigger-only approach.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I think the volume will be a few thousand inserts/updates not too much more. I still am concerned about your point about triggers failing and locking the records mid transaction. 
In your second approach, I would essentially take the insert/update code from trigger and put it into a stored procedure code,and then call the SP from the trigger, correct?

Comment: @SKale . . . Essentially, yes.  I would add additional code for auditing the call to the stored procedure and perhaps some other bells and whistles.

Comment: I have one follow-up question: Is there a way to accomplish this task in C#? Could I for example have a web service that gets triggered in IIS that moves the data from one table to another in intervals of say one hour? -- On a little research I realized this would make the whole thing more difficult I would have to run it in a Windows Scheduled Service.